# Angular app does not set cookies which come from express

Tags: node.js, angular, express, cookies

I am trying to learn backend and frontend and so far I was okey. But now I have a problem.

In my backend which I use Express, I send cookie with res.cookie as shown below

auth.js (/auth route)

```
const register = asyncErrorWrapper(async (req, res, next) => {

    const {name, email, password} = req.body;
    const user = await User.create({
        name,
        email,
        password
    });
   sendJwtToClient(user, res);

});
```

tokenHelper.js

```
const sendJwtToClient = (user, res) => {

    // user modeline gore jwt olusturma

    const token = user.generateJwtFromUser();

    const {JWT_COOKIE, NODE_ENV} = process.env;

    return res
    .status(200)
    .cookie('access_token', token, {
        httpOnly:true,
        expires: new Date(Date.now() + parseInt(JWT_COOKIE) * 1000 * 60),
        secure: NODE_ENV === 'development' ? false : true
    })
    .json({
        success: true,
        access_token: token,
        data: {
            name: user.name,
            email: user.email
        },
        message: 'Your registration is succesful!'
    });
};
```

Then I get response with Angular app in register.component which is connected with Auth Service

from Register.component

```
registerUser() {

    this.sendButton.nativeElement.disabled = true;

    this._authService.registerUser(this.user).subscribe(
      res => {
         if(res.status === 200) {
           console.log(res);
         }
      }, err => {
        console.log(err);
        this.showError.nativeElement.className += ' alert alert-danger';
        this.errMessage = err.error.message;
        this.sendButton.nativeElement.disabled = false;
      })
  }
```

Auth Service

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class AuthService {

  _registerURI = 'http://localhost:3000/auth/register';
  _loginURI = 'http://localhost:3000/auth/login';

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  registerUser(user) {
    return this.http.post<any>(this._registerURI, user, {observe: 'response'});
  };

  loginUser(user) {
    return this.http.post<any>(this._loginURI, user, {observe: 'response'});
  };

};
```

Well I get this response when I click register button: [response](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bSBsW.png)

Btw I use cors package on backend. Thanks in advance.

I can also share other codes, pages whatever you want. I just thought that this is enough.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Okey, got it.

The problem occurred because of the cors policy. To send cookies to the front-end you need to let in cors package.

Here is the options of cors package that used by express:

```
app.use(cors( {
    origin: 'http://localhost:4200',
    allowedHeaders: ['Content-Type', 'Authorization'],
    credentials: true
} ));
```

And this is the Auth Service method posting registration

```
  registerUser(user) {
    return this.http.post<any>(this._registerURI, user, {observe: 'response', withCredentials: true});
  };
```

Comment: this solution not working for me

Answer (score 1):

If setting CORS alone didn't help, make sure you're sending the request from Angular with `withCredentials: true` flag:

```
this.http.get('http://www.url.com', { withCredentials: true });
```

If that didn't work, try setting Angular proxy settings as below:

Change the domain to a prefix in all direct URLs in the angular app. I.e. change http//localhost:3000/your-api-route to the /api/your-api-route. For example:

```
// Change
this.http.post('http://localhost:3000' + '/messages', null, { withCredentials: true });

// To (without 'localhost:3000')
this.http.post('/api/messages', null, { withCredentials: true });
```

Then, create a file proxy.conf.json in your project's src/ folder, and add the following content to it:

```
{
  "/api": {
    "target": "http://localhost:3000",
    "secure": false,
    "pathRewrite": {
            "^/api": ""
        }
  }
}
```

*Note:* `pathRewrite` is used to remove the /api prefix we added when we replaced http://localhost:3000 with /api.

In the CLI configuration file, angular.json, add the proxyConfig option to the serve target:

```
  "architect": {
    "serve": {
      "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:dev-server",
      "options": {
        "browserTarget": "your-application-name:build",
        "proxyConfig": "src/proxy.conf.json"
      },
```

*Explanation why this should help:*
The browser will automatically send the cookie along with the request to the server, only if the cookie's "Domain" attribute matches the domain of the URL being requested.

Since you're running an Angular's development server on port 4200, and an Express API server on a different port (3000), the browser won't attach the cookie from the site running on localhost:4200 along with the request to your express API. Using proxy solves this problem.